# Using BCL classes in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am trying to port a library that relies **heavily** on `System.Security.Cryptography` to run with a Windows Store app. This namespace is completely missing when developing apps for Windows Store.

Which approach should I take here to assure that any apps using the ported library can be approved for the Store, and that would hopefully not involve rearchitecting the entire library by removing the affected namespace?

Answer (score 1):

In WinRT you can use the [Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375276.aspx). This is supported and  and will be used in any feature development.

If you look at the following [API list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) for WinRT you can find what you need under Security.

Comment: Porting a large library that already use the classes from the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace to use completely different classes from `Windows.Security.Cryptopgraphy` was exactly what I am trying to avoid with this question.